# Python: Fix DecodeError when receiving data

Tags: python, unicode, decode

I've searched other post but from what I can tell they all have control of the data being sent to them. In this case I have no control over the data being sent to me. I'm receiving data from an IRC server that I cannot encode specifically to UTF-8 before it is sent. I was wondering if there is anyway to avoid UTF-8 decode errors when receiving data from the socket connected to the IRC channel. 
I'm using python and the line of code I use for receiving is:
data = socket.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')

Any help is appreciated: Thank You

Comment: You could use `try` `except`

Comment: You need to find out what encoding the server is using so you can decode it properly.

Comment: I'm using try except now but I'm losing data doing that. I've tried asking twitch what encoding their server uses but they haven't responded. IRC itself doesn't have a default encoding.

Comment: It's possible that the data is actually encoded with UTF-8, but reading chunks of 2048 bytes might occasionally tear apart a multi-byte character. If that happens, both chunks will cause a UnicodeDecodeError when being decoded individually. The codecs module provides incremental en-/decoders which (I think) can handle such cases.